# How to use REST API mark tests as fail?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

I use this https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/view-test-results/mark-tests-as-pass-fail as reference.
But I not able to let the REST API shows 'fail'. May I know what is my problem? I also attached the text logs, it shows 'Run JavaScript......'
, is it correct?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;  

public class test1 {

    public WebDriver driver = null;

    public static final String USERNAME = "";
    public static final String AUTOMATE_KEY = "";
    public static final String URL = "https://" + USERNAME + ":" + AUTOMATE_KEY + "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub";

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

        caps.setCapability("os", "Windows");
        caps.setCapability("os_version", "10");
        caps.setCapability("browser", "Chrome");
        caps.setCapability("browser_version", "80");

        caps.setCapability("name", "Test1");

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);
    }

    @Test (priority = 1)
    public void test_1() {
        driver.get("https://youtube.com");

        String actualUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/";
        String expectedUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualUrl, expectedUrl);
        
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        
        if (actualUrl.equals(expectedUrl)) {
          jse.executeScript("browserstack_executor: {\"action\": \"setSessionStatus\", \"arguments\": {\"status\": \"passed\", \"reason\": \"Url matched!\"}}");
        }
        else {
          jse.executeScript("browserstack_executor: {\"action\": \"setSessionStatus\", \"arguments\": {\"status\":\"failed\", \"reason\": \"Url not matched\"}}");
        }
    }

    @Test (priority = 2)
    public void test_2() {
        driver.get("https://google.com");

        String actualUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
        String expectedUrl = "https://www.youtube1.com/";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualUrl, expectedUrl);
        
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        
        if (actualUrl.equals(expectedUrl)) {
          jse.executeScript("browserstack_executor: {\"action\": \"setSessionStatus\", \"arguments\": {\"status\": \"passed\", \"reason\": \"Url matched!\"}}");
        }
        else {
          jse.executeScript("browserstack_executor: {\"action\": \"setSessionStatus\", \"arguments\": {\"status\":\"failed\", \"reason\": \"Url not matched\"}}");
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

I tested with youtube and google url.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assert.assertEquals(actualUrl, expectedUrl);
```

is not a soft assert , it will stop the command execution so the test won't reach the api line.

remove that from your tests or use soft assert .

```
SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
softAssert.assertEquals(actualUrl, expectedUrl)
```